# JavaFX WebView: ignoring setPickOnBounds?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I'm attempting to have two transparent WebViews displayed one on top of the other.

They display alright, however, hyperlinks can only clicked for the WebView at the top.

My understanding is that by setting `setPickOnBounds(false)`, clicks on transparent pixels of the top WebView should go through to the bottom WebView. However, it does appear to be work this way, with the top WebView blocking all clicks.

Is there a way to have overlapping WebView with hyperlinks working for both?

Example:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class DoubleWebViews extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        new WebPage(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    static class WebPage{
        WebView webViewBack = new WebView();
        WebView webViewFront = new WebView();
        public WebPage(Stage mainstage){
            setupWebView(webViewBack, "<a href='https://www.google.com'>URL 1</a> can't be clicked!");
            setupWebView(webViewFront, "<br><br><br><a href='https://www.google.com'>URL 2</a>");

            StackPane root = new StackPane(webViewBack, webViewFront);
            root.setPickOnBounds(false);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            mainstage.setScene(scene);
            mainstage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        void setupWebView(WebView webView, String html){
            webView.setPickOnBounds(false); // doesn't work?
            WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            webEngine.documentProperty().addListener(new DocListener(webEngine));
            webEngine.loadContent("<body style='background : rgba(0,0,0,0);font-size: 70px;text-align:center;'>" + html + "</body>");
        }

        static class DocListener implements ChangeListener<Document>{
            private final WebEngine webEngine;
            public DocListener(WebEngine webEngine) { this.webEngine = webEngine;}
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> observable, Document oldValue, Document newValue) {
                try {
                    // Use reflection to retrieve the WebEngine's private 'page' field.
                    Field f = this.webEngine.getClass().getDeclaredField("page");
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    com.sun.webkit.WebPage page = (com.sun.webkit.WebPage) f.get(this.webEngine);
                    page.setBackgroundColor((new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)).getRGB());
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not found an elegant solution yet, but this works.

First, the mouse events received by the front `WebView` `webViewFront` need to be forwarded to `webViewBack`:

```java
webViewFront.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> webViewBack.fireEvent(event));
```

This will enable clicks, drags, etc to work on both frames.

As for using the correct cursor, that is a little tricky. Only the cursor of the front `WebView` is displayed. Therefore, our back WebView must be allowed to modify the front cursor:

```java
webViewBack.cursorProperty().addListener((obs, oldCursor, newCursor) -> webViewFront.setCursor(newCursor));
```

The problem is now that `webViewFront` constantly resets its cursor to default if a mouse event occurs and there is no hyperlinks at that location in `webViewFront`. Therefore, we  prevent this reset:

```java
webViewFront.cursorProperty().addListener((obs, oldCursor, newCursor) -> {
    if (newCursor != null && "DEFAULT".equals(newCursor.toString())) {
        webViewFront.setCursor(webViewBack.getCursor());
    }
});
```

Together, these three changes allow two overlapping WebView with hyperlinks working for both.